Ошибка в типах (JS)
Решаю задачу на Codewars, ссылка:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/670031c78cc02fa6c28ba28a/train/javascript
Получаю ошибку:

"return BigInt(sum); RangeError: The number Infinity cannot be converted to a BigInt because it"

Как преобразовать infinity к BigInt, или нужно пропускать Infinity?
Когда пропускаю Infinity получаю другие результаты — как исправить?
Работает только с маленькими n:

С тысячными n уже ошибка:

Код:
function channellingPrimes(n) {
    const res = 0;
    const bits = [];
    let sum = 0;
  
    function isPrime( num ) {
        if( num <= 1 )
            return false;
        
        for( i = 2; i * i <= num; i ++) { 
            if( num % i == 0 ) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
  
    for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            bits.push(1);
        } else {
            bits.push(0);
        }
    }
  
    for(let i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
        if(bits[i] === 1) {
            sum += Math.pow(2, i);
        }
    }
    
    return BigInt(sum);
}

console.log(channellingPrimes(4800));


Условие задачи приведите. Вот этот момент ещё сомнительный sum += Math.pow(2, i);

никак, надо просто использовать BigInt и не получать infinity

добавь ссылку на задачу codewars

что то мне подсказывает, что 2 в больше чем 64й степени в не посчитаете никак обычными средствами. А если даже посчитали бы, то вряд ли этот алгоритм уложится в таймилимит.

Загрузил, попробовать с BigInt изначально?

sum BigInt и добавляемая степень двойки тоже (считать через 1n<<i). Однако для n=10000 длинный вывод получится

Ну да, нужно изначально переменную sum завести как BigInt, а не потом пытаться преобразовывать, когда уже поздно.

на самом деле Math.pow даже делать не надо, можно просто строку из битов собрать и передать в конструктор BigInt

Вместо Math.pow использовал ** и изначально переменная sum BigInt, сработало, всем спасибо
